# polymorphism java q from a test

Tags: java

I have a question regarding to polymorphism

```
public class A 
{ 
 protected int _i; 

 public A(int i) 
 { 
 _i = i; 
 } 
} 

//----------------------------------------------------------// 
public class B extends A 
{ 
 public B(int i) 
 { 
 super(i+1); 
 } 
} 

//----------------------------------------------------------// 
public class C extends B 
{ 
 public C(int i) 
 { 
 super(i); 
 } 

 public boolean equals (Object other) 
 { 
 return ((other!=null) && 
 (other instanceof C) && 
 (_i==((C) other)._i)); 
 } 
} 

//----------------------------------------------------------// 
public class D extends B 
{ 
 public D(int i) 
 { 
 super(i+1); 
 } 

 public boolean equals (D other) 
 { 
 return ((other!=null) && 
 (_i==((D) other)._i)); 
 } 
} 


public class tester {
    public static void main (String [] args) { 
         A a = new A(1); 
         B b = new B(1); 
         C c = new C(1); 
         D d = new D(1); 
         B b1 = new D(1); 
         Object c1 = new C(1); 
         Object d1 = new D(1); 


    System.out.println (d1.equals(d)); 

    } 
}
```

Why the printed result is false ?
when I change the equals method in D to receive Object instead of D it's printing True but way?
Please help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You already got half the answer. "when I change the equals method in D to receive Object instead of D it's printing True" is actually the key part of this problem. What you need to understand is the difference between overriding and overloading.

```
public boolean equals (D other) 
{ 
  return ((other!=null) && 
     (_i==((D) other)._i)); 
}
```

This method will create a version of `equals(D d)` specific to the `D` class, **in addition to** the preexisting `equals(Object o)` in `Object`. This is because they have **different method signatures**, and is called **overloading**. This, however, works perfectly:

```
public boolean equals (Object other) 
{ 
  return ((other!=null) && 
     (_i==((D) other)._i)); 
}
```

This is because it **overrides** the superclass version of `equals(Object o)`. One final note. I know you didn't write this code, but it's good practice to write this method more like this:

```
public boolean equals (Object other) 
{ 
  if(other instanceof D)
        return ((other!=null) && (_i==((D) other)._i));
  return false; 
}
```

This way you can avoid a `ClassCastException` if you try to compare a `D` to an unrelated object, or one that is lower in the inheritance tree.